# Use jQuery to make hidden div appear in same place of visible div (then hide prev visible div)

Tags: jquery, css

If a user makes a certain selection from a drop down list of elements, I need to make a hidden `div` visible and a visible `div` hidden. The `div` that is currently visible, though, has to be in the same place on the page as the previously visible `div`.

If they are both shown together on the page (both visible) they need to be positioned one on top of the other (i.e. stacked so if you are scrolling down the page one elements appears prior to the other).

How would I use jQuery to go about this kind of positioning?

Comment: if i understand your question correctly, you can simply position them `absolute` with the same `left:` and `top:` values.

Comment: When you say << on top of the other >> do you mean it should be stacked ?

Comment: @Joybroto: Yes, sorry I'll clarify in my post. Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to overcomplicate things. Simply place them in a parent `<div>`:

```
<div>
   <div class="a">A</div>
   <div class="b">B</div>
</div>
```

Whenever `.a` is hidden using `display:none`, `.b` will be in it's position, and vice-versa.

When both are shown, `.b` will be underneath `.a` as you wished.

Comment: isn't `.b` jumping if `.a` gets `display: none;`?

Comment: This does exactly what I needed. I just use .show()/.hide() and the two divs position themselves right where they need to be. Thanks again!

Comment: @supersize If both `.a` and `.b` are visible, and you hide `.a`, then the browser will reflow the content and there could be a visible jump in the position of various page elements.

Comment: @MarcAudet There are many ways around that problem using jQuery though :)